# Is it possible to freely intersperse vim panes from the same session and other shell panes in tmux?

Tags: vim, tmux

I would like to have arbitrary arrangements of vim and other terminal panes within tmux.  This is a simple example:

```
------------------------------------
|           |            |         |
|           |            |         |
|           |            |         |
|   VIM     |   NOT VIM  |   VIM   |
|           |            |         |
|           |            |         |
|           |            |         |
------------------------------------
```

I know I can do this if I use two separate Vim sessions for the left and right panes.  But I would like both to keep all Vims within the same session-- i.e. all with access to the same set of open buffers.  Is it possible to have such multiple non-adjacent vim windows within the  same session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to achieve something like that layout is with window splits in Vim, and a (rather poorly) emulated terminal (e.g. with the [Conque Shell - Run interactive commands inside a Vim buffer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) in the middle.

Unlike *Emacs*, Vim does not have a separation of server and (multiple) view clients.

Comment: Ah-- good to know.  Yes, I've tried Conque and found there were too many minor irritations to make it worth using.

Answer (score 1):

One Vim = one session.

You can't share a session between two Vim instances.